# How can I convert a specific .cs file into either a .bat or a .exe file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, csc

I am trying to convert around 1,900 .txp files (a proprietary Sony image format) to .png. However, the .exe program I am using to convert these files only allows me to select one file at a time.

I am running Windows 7.

There's a TXP.CS file in the 'src' folder of the program, so I figured that if I was able to turn that into an executable file, I'd be able to use it to mass convert these files to PNG.

However, whenever I try to convert the file using csc.exe, I get the **CS0246** error (the type or namespace name 'Tools' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I can't use Microsoft Visual Studio right now, so I'm hoping someone can walk me through this, or maybe convert the file to either a .bat or an .exe for me. Thank you.

[TXP.CS](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B17QScG8CEUJei1iMHJBaEk3TGM/edit?usp=drive_web)

Comment: 1. Are all of the files in the same folder?  2. Are there files in subfolders? 3. What is the syntax for executing the .exe program?  4. Does it work by you just passing it parameters; or do you have to answer questions in a GUI?  5. If you have been answering questions in a GUI maybe you can do NameOfExe.exe /? and have it give info on passing parameters.  Then we should be able to execute it repetively in a FOR loop.

Comment: 1. The .exe program uses additional files that are stored in different folders like 'src', if that's what you mean. 2. Yes. 3. I just double-click it and it opens like any normal executable program. 4. I am extremely sorry, but I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. I've never dealt with .cs files before, nor do I know much about the things you mentioned. Do you want me to run csc xxx.exe txp.cs? Can you give me the exact command? Thank you.

Comment: open a CMD prompt, navigate to the folder that the executable is in, type NAMEOFYOUREXECUTABLE.EXE /?   If you are lucky it will post some useful information that you can post to get us going.

Comment: Unfortunately, all that does is open the program. Ah, well. Thank you for being so patient with me.

Comment: If you have any documentation on the .exe you might look for info on running from a CMD prompt or bat file.  We may be able to pass filenames to it.  What is the name of this .exe?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work with the exe file that converts one file at a time.

The exact commands depend on the syntax of the .exe file.

```
@echo off
for /r %%a in (*.txp) do "c:\folder\sony_exe_file.exe" "%%a" "%%~dpa\%%~na.png"
```

Above `"%%a"` will be replaced with `"c:\folder\file.txp"`
and `"%%~dpa\%%~na.png"` will be replaced with `"c:\folder\file.png"`
and will loop through every `.txp` file.

Comment: I tried making a .bat file out of this, with this as my command: @echo off
for /r %%a in (*.txp) do "C:\Users\me\Desktop\ TXP\tool_sony.exe" "%%a" "%%~dpa\%%~na.png" but all that did was open the program... nothing else happened. Thank you for help, though.

Comment: I assumed the program worked at the command line.  It would seem to be a GUI interactive program - but an `AutoIt` script may help you there.